# Alfresco 5.x WCM / Web QUick Start

Tags: alfresco, wcm

I am relatively new to ALfresco, but have alreay installed the 5.0.d Version once experimentilly and now try to set up the 201510 EA Version.

I am struggling with the set up of the Web Quick Start.
I noted from the earlier installation that the meat data need to have the real domain name instead of the localhost / 127.0.0.1 IP adress.

Unfortunately I can't find the meta settings anymore.

I have tried also to install the system with the domain name instead of the localhost  during the setup, but no difference. All I get is

```
Spring Surf 1.0.0 
Spring Surf has been installed at this location. 
A root page has not been defined.
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

**EDIT**

Found the metadata at the `Quick Start Editorial`and `Quick Start Live` folder. Then the metadate (or Eigenschaften in German) can be edited. Nevertheless it did not solve the issue yet (as it did in 5.0.0.d)

**EDIT-2**

I have found the following warnings in the `webquickstart.log`:

```
19:20:27,889 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.impl.WebSiteServiceImpl] Received a request for unrecognised host+port: sbd.mydom.tld:8080/wcmqs
19:20:27,890 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.interceptor.ApplicationDataInterceptor] Received request for which no configured website can be found: sbd.mydom.tld:8080
19:20:27,890 ERROR [org.alfresco.wcm.client.exceptionresolver.RepositoryExceptionResolver] org.alfresco.wcm.client.exception.PageNotFoundException: sbd.mydom.tld:8080
org.alfresco.wcm.client.exception.PageNotFoundException: sbd.mydom.tld:8080
        at org.alfresco.wcm.client.interceptor.ApplicationDataInterceptor.preHandle(ApplicationDataInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:134)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:928)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2403)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/web-content-services/awe-not-working-42a-10242012-1328

Does this link help? Someone has the same problem as you (I think it's the same) and he writes that he solved it with:

> I just realized I need to edit properties on the folders that contain the content. I changed the IP address and it now works on my external IP address.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have found the Metadata entries and adapted it, but unfortunatly this didn't change the behaviour.

The metadata is ONLY located at the `Quick Start Editorial` folder.

Comment: You already see this? https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/web-content-services/wcmqs-dont-run-when-install-community-34-edition 
for your EDIT-2

Comment: Yes,. I have set the Mate data entries now (hopefully correct, but it's the same as with some examples)
I have now found that the error message, references the logo with a different dir-structure than actually on the server. So maybe this might be a reason, if this applies to the whole system.
As far as I am aware, there are some major changes going on, so this might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported a demo site or created from scratch the necessary index.html page? Try to use the following link: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/WQS-import-demodata.html

Comment: Yes I have imported the demo site during the ALF Installation and also created the demo site accoding the description. I have also changed the URL from 127.0.0.1 to my servers name.

Comment: it's annoying because I worked with AWQS several years ago and I know that this is a very common problem that has a simple solution. unfortunately I do not remember what it was. If you can access share on a given host:port, it has to work with awqs as well. Be sure that only one site has the hostname and port that you are using. The configuration for the editorial site has to be different from the configuration of the live site. try to use directly the IP address and verify that it works for share.

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes involved here:

[ApplicationDataInterceptor.java](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/web-apps/Share/trunk/wcmquickstart-module/wcmquickstartwebsite/src/main/java/org/alfresco/wcm/client/interceptor/ApplicationDataInterceptor.java)

[WebSiteServiceImpl.java](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/web-apps/Share/trunk/wcmquickstart-module/wcmquickstartclientapi/src/main/java/org/alfresco/wcm/client/impl/WebSiteServiceImpl.java)

ApplicationDataInterceptor calls WebSiteServiceImpl to get the site based on host, port and context-path.

As you can see, WebSiteServiceImpl executes a CMIS query to find all the registered sites:

```
private static final String QUERY_WEB_ROOTS = "select f.cmis:objectId, w.ws:hostName, w.ws:hostPort, t.cm:title, t.cm:description, w.ws:webAppContext, w.ws:siteConfig "
        + "from cmis:folder as f "
        + "join ws:website as w on w.cmis:objectId = f.cmis:objectId "
        + "join cm:titled as t on t.cmis:objectId = f.cmis:objectId";
```

If you set the log level for WebSiteServiceImpl to debug, you will find this query in the log.
You can then execute it in the query browser and see what it returns. You should see your site. Based on the error returned, it seems that there is another site configured with the same ip/port/context and that does not have a root index page.

Answer (score 0):

I have now installed the latest Version of Alfresco (201602) and got everything to work as expected.

The major difference to the previous installation was that I did not change the

```
Webserver-Domäne: [127.0.0.1]:
```

from the preset value.
During the last installation I tried to set the domain-name here, which seems that this was the issue.

As a second step needed to set the domain information in the meta-data of the folder `Quick Start Editorial` as described above.

Now it works.